# SubSonic and app.config in Windows Form

Tags: winforms, configuration, subsonic, app-config

As it should be the file app.config in an application Windows Form so that the given access classes her they generate automatically in the build?

Comment: I think the question [restated] is "How do I configure my app.config so that the subsonic classes automatically generate as part of the build?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you do is add a section in configSections called "SubsonicService", like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
```

Next, you add a connectionStrings branch with the connection strings that you will use in your project, like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="WheelMUDSQLite" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Dev\WheelMud.net\src\SQL\SQLite\WheelMud.net.db;Version=3;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Last, you add the SubsonicService node that you added in the configSections like this:

```
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="WheelMUDSQLite">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="WheelMUDSQLite" type="SubSonic.SQLiteDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="WheelMUDSQLite" generatedNamespace="WheelMUD.DataLayer"/>
    </providers>
</SubSonicService>
```

This is where you put all of your providers. I use the SubStage utility to generate the DAL. This way you can completely disassociate your stuff from the Web bits that come with Subsonic.

Answer (score 1):

Your build process needs to include a command like this:

```
sonic.exe generate /config "c:\myproject\App.config"
```

sonic.exe is the [SubCommander](http://subsonicproject.com/subcommander/using-the-command-line-tool-subcommander/) utility, and is included in the [current release](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/). There's no way to have the app.config handle this for you directly.

One way to run the command is with [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452(VS.80).aspx). The [Exec MS Build task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd(VS.80).aspx) task might look something like this:

```
<Target Name="GenerateSubSonicClasses" DependsOn="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="sonic.exe generate /config &quot;c:\myproject\App.config&quot;" WorkingDirectory="c:\path-to-subcommander"/>
</Target>
```

I just made this up, so it probably needs tweaking before it'll work for you. This command would go in your *visual studio project* file (ie *someproject.vbproj*).